# Matlab installation problem

Tags: matlab

While installing the Matlab 2014 in Ubuntu 14.04, a single error has occurred as follows:

```
Error: Cannot locate Java Runtime Environment (JRE).
The directory /home/zina/Documents/Matlab/matlab_2014/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre does not exist.
```

Could someone assist me in attempting to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you should refer to(http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231238/get-an-error-when-trying-to-install-matlab-2014a-on-debian) and (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB). As per those links you need openJDK/JRE 6.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are having is that you need JRE (Java Runtime Environment)  on your computer to use Matlab. To install, execute the following commands ***AS ROOT:***

```
java -version
```

This will check to see if you have java installed. If not, proceed to the next steps.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install default-jre
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

What this will do is install the Java Runtime Environment, and also the Java Development Kit, incase of future use of more advanced software. After that, you're done! You should now be able to successfully install Matlab.